# Python blogging, wordpress_xmlrpc doesn’t ‘publish’

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I am trying the lines in Python wordpress_xmlrpc documentation, http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html.

Here is what I have:

```
wp = Client('https://remembertochange.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'user', 'pass')
posts = wp.call(GetPosts())

post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'My new title'
post.content = 'This is the body of my new post.'

post.terms_names = {
  'post_tag': ['test', 'firstpost'],
  'category': ['Introductions', 'Tests']
}

wp.call(NewPost(post))

post.post_status = 'publish'
```

The problem is it only adds a draft to the blog, and doesn’t publish it as a new post to the blog.

What’s wrong with it, and how can I correct it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting post.post_status = 'publish' before calling wp.call(NewPost(post))?

Comment: @Furkan Omay, you are such a genius! would you mind give it as an answer so that I can choose it?

Comment: I did :) I suppose it solved your problem.

Comment: @Furkan Omay, marvelous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official documentation](http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/posts.html), posts will be sent as drafts by default.

Here, you modify the post_status property of WordPressPost object *after* you sent that post to the server. Thus, it's only changed in local memory and server does not see the change.

Simply, putting

```
post.post_status = 'publish'
```

before you make the call wp.call(NewPost(post)) will make it work as the way you want.